# how to verify a void function is been called in spring integration test

Tags: java, spring, java-8, integration-testing, verify

I have wrote an integration for testing a delete function like as shown below

```
@Test
void deleteUsersTest() {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("id", "21");
    this.template.delete("/v1/users/{id}", params);
    :
}
```

The problem I am facing is, since it is a void function I would like to verify the below function is been called internally

```
userRepository.deleteById(21)
```

In Unit test I usually used something like this

```
verify(userRepository, times(1)).deleteById((long) 21);
```

but the above one is mockito based function which I cannot used in Integration test

Can someone help me on how to verify this function in Spring Integration test

I am using Spring 5, Spring Boot 2.1

Comment: Can you show code ? are you mocking `userRepository` ?

Comment: @Deadpool I am not mocking ‘userRepository’, its an integration test running under Spring context . ‘userRepository’ is been ‘@Autowired’ in the test class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration testing happens on a real database. Just ensure that the entity is stored in your database before calling `delete` and not stored in your database after calling `delete`.

```
@BeforeEach
public void setDatabase() {
    client1 = new Client();
    client1.setName("Karl");
    client2 = new Client();
    client2.setName("Pauline");

    testEntityManager.persist(client1);
    testEntityManager.persist(client2);
    testEntityManager.flush();
}
```

```
@Test
public void deleteTest() {
    clientRepository.deleteById(client1.getId());

    List<Client> clientListActual = clientRepository.findAll();
    boolean clientExists = clientListActual.contains(client1);

    assertFalse(clientExists);
    assertEquals(1, clientListActual.size());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [@SpyBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html), here is the example using [spybean](https://shekhargulati.com/2017/07/20/using-spring-boot-spybean/)

> Spy wraps the real bean but allows you to verify method invocation and mock individual methods without affecting any other method of the real bean. So, by making `userRepository` a SpyBean we can mock only the methods we want to mock in our test case and leave the others untouched.

Another way you can also use `@MockBean` to create a mock and use `thenCallRealMethod()` to call real method

```
@MockBean
private UserRepository userRepository
```

And then say call a real method

```
// Call a real method of a Mocked object
when(userRepository.deleteById(21l)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

So using the above statement it actually calls the real method, and now you can verify it

```
verify(userRepository, times(1)).deleteById(21l);
```

Comment: Still cant we not do the verify in integration test to check if the function is been called or not...